# How to link to img src using HTML email template in WordPress

Tags: images, html

I am using the Ultimate Member plugin on my website, to create user accounts. As part of this plugin, they allow you to customise the HTML email templates. I am trying to add an image as part of this email, using an image that I have uploaded using the WordPress media area.

To link to the image, I am using ''.

However, when the email comes through, the image is not there.

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to link the image to a relative path `../wp-content/`.
For the link to work in an e-mail, where the path isn't known to the reader, you must use the complete full path including `http://` or `https://`.

Like this: `http://yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/logo-full.jpg`

Comment: Thank you! I thought I tried this, but apparently not as it is now working.